# Reversing a Generic Array using "in situ"

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, generics, reverse

For this generic array I added method reverse() that has to reverse the array without using an additional array of elements and I am trying to perform the reverse “in situ” using only swap operations. But I may have gotten it wrong and if so how can it be reversed “in situ” using only swap operations?

```
import java.util.Collections;

class GenericArray<E> {
    private E[] array;
    private int size;

    public GenericArray() {
        array = (E[]) new Object[10];
        size = 0;
    }

    public E get(int i) {
        return array[i];
    }

    public void set(int i, E value) {
        if (i < size)
            array[i] = value;
    }

    public void add(E value) {
        array[size++] = value;
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        return size == array.length;
    }

    public void remove(int i) {
        for (int j = i; j < size; j++)
            array[j] = array[j + 1];
        size--;
    }

    public void insert(int i, E value) {
        for (int j = size; j >= i; j--)
            array[j + 1] = array[j];
        array[i] = value;
        size++;
    }

    public void display() {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }

    public E reverse() {

        Collections.reverse(array);

    }

}
```

Comment: There is no method on [`Collections`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) that takes an array argument...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that you want to do it manually without using `Collections.reverse` (that code shouldn't even compile btw, reverse needs a `List` as parameter), just traverse the array from the beginning to the middle swapping elements at the opposite sides of the range:

```
public E[] reverse() {
    for (int i = 0; i < size/2; i++){
        E tmp=array[i];  
        array[i] = array[size - i - 1];
        array[size - i - 1]=tmp;
    }
    return array; // If you really want to return it
}
```

More info on [*in situ* algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm) on wikipedia.

Regarding an `add` implementation that ensures that there is enough space:

```
public void add(E value) {
    int newsize=size+1;
    if(newsize<size){
        //The array is big enough, add the element
        array[newsize]=value;
    }else{
        //The array is too small, create a new one with
        //the old content but twice as bigger and add 
        //the new element
        array=Arrays.copyOf(array,size*2); 
        array[newsize]=value;  
    }
    size=newsize;
}
```

Comment: so I guess this would be considered an "in situ"  without using an additional array of elements and using only swap operations.

Comment: Yes, "in situ" is latin for "in place", that 3 lines are performing the swap.

Comment: oh! I thought that "in situ" meant something special in programming and in Java.

Comment: Actually it does, on wikipedia they even use the same algorithm as example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm

Comment: also @uraimo how could I correct the add() method in order to increase the size of the stored array because adding an element when the array is full is no longer possible. Also how could I correct the insert method() to increase the size of the stored array because inserting an element when the array is full is no longer possible?

Comment: The problem there is that the array has a fixed size. What you should do is: 1- Increment `size` 2- check if the array is smaller than size 3- if it's smaller  you need to create a new *bigger* array (usually the size is doubled) and copy the stuff of the old array to the new one (`Arrays.copyOfRange`).

Comment: So @uraimo should I do number 1 for the add() and do 2 and 3 for insert() using the `(Arrays.copyOfRange)`?

Comment: Yes, copyOfRange simply copies stuff from one array to another.

Comment: Actually @uraimo I just noticed that `array[size++] = value;` with the `size` in the add() method is already being incremented. so maybe leave that alone or how could I increment it because I am not seeing it.

Comment: When size++ will exceed array.length you'll get an ArrayIndexOutOfBound exception, you need to check if size++>array.length before using it as index for array.

Comment: Oh! so @uraimo you mean like this `if (size++ > array.length) { array[size++] = value;}`

Comment: Better assigning size++ to a newsize variable (you there are incrementing two times!) and assign if **<**, add and else there and create a new array[size*2]and then copy array into newarray with copyOfRange (after this assign newarray to array). And then assign newsize to size.

Comment: Added an example of `add` method, the insert one is similar.

Comment: Oh, okay then how would the insert() method be similar @uraimo? I'm not sure of the similarity, could you show that too?

Answer (score 0):

`Collections.reverse()` does reversal "in situ"; you just need to give it the array as a list:

```
Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Comment: Thanks! right now if you look at what uraimo and I were talking about I am trying to "correct the add() method in order to increase the size of the stored array because adding an element when the array is full is no longer possible. Also correct the insert method() to increase the size of the stored array because inserting an element when the array is full is no longer possible"